# Уникальное имя перемены в цикле for Javascript?

Tags: javascript

использую яндекс карту и что бы можно было добавлять новые маркеры из HTML сделал такой код

```
 var mapObjectsAll = document.getElementsByClassName('map-object')


      for(var i = 0; i<mapObjectsAll.length; i++){

        var itemK = mapObjectsAll[i];
        var titleK = $(itemK).data('name')
        var latK = $(itemK).data('lat')
        latK = parseFloat(latK)
        var lonK = $(itemK).data('lon')
        lonK = parseFloat(lonK)
        var hitcontent = $(itemK).data('hitcontent')
        var bilHeader = $(itemK).data('bilheader')
        var bilCenter = $(itemK).data('bilcenter')
        var bilFooter = $(itemK).data('bilfooter')



        var myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark([latK, lonK], {
          hintContent: hitcontent,
          balloonContentHeader: bilHeader,
          balloonContentBody: bilCenter,
          balloonContentFooter: bilFooter,
        }, {
          iconLayout: 'default#image',
          iconImageHref: 'static/img/assets/map/marker.svg',
          iconImageSize: [40,40],
          iconImageOffset: [-26, -46]        
        });

      }



      myMap.geoObjects
        .add(myPlacemark)
```

( Это часть кода)

Все бы окей, только есть одна проблема. Как быть с переменной myPlacemark - ведь в каждом цикле она должна быть уникальной и позже получать ее за пределами цикла что бы можно было добавить как параметр, заранее спасибо

Comment: сложите ссылки в массив или объект..

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, они и так в `.geoObjects
        .add` складываются

Comment: @Grundy нет не добавляются. Внизу же есть код который добавляет в ручную .add

И у меня проблема с синтаксом. Как именно сделать что бы имя переменной каждый раз была новая

Comment: @Grundy я полагаю там помойка, тк это все объекты карты, нужно завести объект с известными ключами или массив, в котором понятно что лежит

Comment: @Danielqwaqwaqwa, а, форматирование плохое, показалось что add внутри цикла. Так что просто перенеси add внутрь цикла

Comment: или просто надо перенести добавление в тело цикла и я не правильно сперва понял что тут не так

Comment: @Grundy почти синхронно, я тоже подумал что add в теле и задача в другом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете перенести `myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark)` в сам цикл или воспользоваться ответом выше.

Answer (score 0):

```
var markers = [];
for (var i = 0; i < coords.length; ++i) {
    markers[i] = "some stuff";
}
```